# How to know view name in run time in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have more than 3 views and also one window view ( pdfReader.xib nib file). I have a screen which is containing chapter name that is representing by table view. Whenever any row selected related chapeter is being load. I am controlling with different view. I want to know which view is being load in my "pdfReader.m" file. So i will load pdf file for reading. I am loading my view like below code.

I have written code of selection of row in

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
..........
.........


    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"!!!!!!");
            pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter1;
            break;
        case 1:
            //pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter2;
            break;
        case 2:
            //pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter3;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

...
...
}
```

I want to which view are coming to load in pdfReader.m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign an **tag** value with each of your view. **(When you create your views with `init` method)**

```
 pdfReader.Chapter1.tag = 1;
 pdfReader.Chapter2.tag = 2;
 pdfReader.Chapter3.tag = 3;
```

Now modify your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    {

       if(pdfReader.view.tag == 1)
       {
          //First chapter used 
       }
       else if(pdfReader.view.tag == 2)
       {       
            //Second chapter used 
       }
       else if(pdfReader.view.tag == 3)
       {
            //third chapter used 
       }
       ..........................
       ..........................
       ..........................

      switch (indexPath.row)
      {
      case 0:
           pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter1;
        break;
      case 1:
           //pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter2;
        break;
      case 2:
           //pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter3;
        break;

      default:
        break;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Where and what i will have to write to see view name in pdfreader.m file ?

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar : (When you create your views with init method) see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for answer. But i have to write for pdf file loading in my pdfcontroller page. Which is containing many views. Is it possible to which views are loading so i will fetch its related pdf file in pdfController. like below code but this is not working. I wrote this in viwLoad function.

if(self.view.tag==1)
  NSLog(@"!!3333333!1111");

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a reference to the PDFView object to the TableView in your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Every UI object of the UIKit has a field called `tag` this property can be used to set any kind of integral variable. An approach would be:

```
pdfReader.tag = indexPath.row;
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter1;
        break;
    case 1:
        //pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter2;
        break;
    case 2:
        //pdfReader.view = pdfReader.Chapter3;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

The only thing I'm not sure about is, if it is advisable to prepare a view for each chapter because you might run into memory conditions if the number of chapter increases.

Comment: Is it not a good idea to make different views for each chapter ? If not then what is the proper way. Please explain me ?

Comment: Try to reuse the UIViews you create, if you open PDF files, reassign the content of the PDFs to the views you are using. By this you only need to keep track of the PDF.